# pointers and struct issues

Tags: c++

I am trying to add two polynomials,

The following code works for polynomials like 1+2x+3x^2 and 1+x+x^2 but not when the adding 1+2x+3x^2 and 1+1x+x^3...

Note the coefficients are stored in a dynamic array, and even if the term is not present we account for it. i.e 1+1x+x^3 is input as degree:3 coefficients 1 1 0 1. I also need to account for when adding two polynomials that cancel eachother out. i.e +3x^2+(-3x^2)=0..Any suggestions on how I can think about these two scenarios.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you're asking -- perhaps you can provide some more context, or an example showing what you're looking for? Be sure also to check the [question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this does not work when the degrees of the two polynomials are different is that the loop has undefined behavior: it goes on to the `max-1`, but the index at `max-1` is valid on only one of the two polynomials.

Your code in the loop needs to check if the index `i` is less than `a->degree` before accessing `a->coeffs[i]`, and that the index `i` is less than `b->degree` before accessing `b->coeffs[i]`:

```
for(int i=0; i<=max; i++)
    sum[i] = (i <= a->degree ? a->coeffs[i] : 0)
           + (i <= b->degree ? b->coeffs[i] : 0);
```

This would let you avoid accessing data past the end of the `coeffs` arrays.

Comment: oh I thought of merge sort when, we do something similar there! thank you

Comment: @user2809437 The fix that I posted should do the trick - the conditional expressions will guard against accessing past the end of the array. Simply replace your `sum[i]=a->coeffs[i]+b->coeffs[i];` with it, and the code will work.

Comment: I did i<= a-> degree and i<= b-> that gave me the correct values! thank you again